# Is it possible to get notified if user clicks on UITableView sectionIndex

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to change the the color of the section index of an `UITableView`, if the user clicks on it.

I can set the `sectionIndexColor` and the `sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor` while initializing the tableview and on any other state, but I've found no method to change the index color on click.

Update:

I mean the A-Z side bar at larger tableviews. Here are some images (see grey bar at image 2)

Unselected state:

[image]

Selected state:
[image]

Comment: you mean selected cell color change...?or section selection then section color change?

Comment: do you want to change the colors of the whole index or just of the selected item?

Comment: @Jonathan Cichon: only the whole index. At unselected state it should have dark color and in selected state a lighter color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only a rather dirty solution for this, as apple does not support it with a public api. My implemention works quit good and should not crash if some api changes in the future (just will not work anymore). I am subclassing the `UITableView` and adding my own callbacks to the sectionIndex View on the time it is added as a subview to the table.

```
@interface MyTableView : UITableView

@end

@implementation MyTableView

- (void)selectionStarted {
    [self setSectionIndexColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}

- (void)selectionStoped {
    [self setSectionIndexColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}

- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view {
    [super addSubview:view];
    if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"] && [view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {
        UIControl *cont = (UIControl *)view;
        [cont addTarget:self action:@selector(selectionStarted) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [cont addTarget:self action:@selector(selectionStoped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cont addTarget:self action:@selector(selectionStoped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
        [cont addTarget:self action:@selector(selectionStoped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I can't risk that the app is rejected by using a private api (although just comparing the names).

Comment: you are not calling any private api, so i dont think apple will reject it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITableView` delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Then modify needed section, you have indexPath.

The easiest way - just to keep indexPath as a property and reload `tableView`, then in `viewForHeaderInSection` you should compare indexPath and set color you want.